# Apollo graphql error Type 'DocumentNode' is not assignable to type 'string | DocumentNode | undefined'

Tags: typescript, testing, graphql, apollo-server

I'm trying to write a test for my graphql 'route' and I'm running into some errors. The route works perfectly well inside the graphql playground but in my tests I'm getting the error `Type 'DocumentNode' is not assignable to type 'string | DocumentNode | undefined'.`.

My test looks like this: [image]

And the error is this: [image]

Answer (score 2):

for anyone else who ended up here, I got the error `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'DocumentNode | TypedDocumentNode<unknown, { arguments: { id: string; }; }> apollo` when I forgot to add `gql` to my query

I did

```
export const explainFailure = ` // forgot to add gql
query ($arguments: ExecutionExplainArguments!) {
    execution(arguments: $arguments) {
        id

    }
}
`;
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to import gql from the same package that you are importing graphQL client from so they match type exactly when it comes to gql/nodeDocument.